# When do I need to cast the result of malloc in C language?

Tags: c, malloc

Based on [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) `malloc` returns a pointer to `void` that it

> is automatically and safely promoted to any other pointer type

But reading K&R I've found this following code

```
char *strdup(char *s)
{
char *p;
/* make a duplicate of s */
p = (char *) malloc(strlen(s)+1)
```

What is the difference?

Comment: I think `K&R` is an old book, and apparently old compilers didn't do this correctly.

Comment: Very very old versions of C did not have (void*) so a cast was needed to pass "lint". Your compiler NEVER needs the cast.

Comment: Cast in C++ and not in C. Though the use of `malloc()` would be discouraged over `new` and `delete`. If your compiler is giving you warnings, time to switch a compiler.

Comment: That's from the second edition (since it uses prototypes). The unnecessary cast is a little surprising.

Comment: This particular cast isn't needed in ANY version of C, because the return type of malloc() would be either a (void*) or a (char*) so no C messages either way. Exactly what "lint" would do is another matter. (C++ OTOH has redefined (void*) from "pointer to anything" to "pointer to nothing" so it doesn't really count.)

Comment: @user3710044: As I've stated in my answer, and as iharob said --- it's entirely possible that certain ancient non-compliant compilers had trouble with that. That was *then* though, and *nowadays*, good luck finding a compiler with this problem.

Comment: Note that the quote about promotions is not entirely correct.  A `void *` is automatically and safely promoted to any pointer *to object* type, but not to any function pointer.

Answer (score 8):

For any implementation conforming to C89 or later, casting the result of `malloc()` is never necessary.

Casting the result of `malloc()` is mentioned in the [Errata for *The C Programming Language, Second Edition*](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html):

> 142(§6.5, toward the end): The remark about casting the return value
>   of malloc ("the proper method is to declare ... then explicitly
>   coerce") needs to be rewritten. The example is correct and works, but
>   the advice is debatable in the context of the 1988-1989 ANSI/ISO
>   standards. It's not necessary (given that coercion of `void *` to
>   `ALMOSTANYTYPE *` is automatic), and possibly harmful if `malloc`, or a
>   proxy for it, fails to be declared as returning `void *`. The explicit
>   cast can cover up an unintended error. On the other hand, pre-ANSI,
>   the cast was necessary, and it is in C++ also.

(That link is no longer valid. The late Dennis Ritchie's home page is now [here](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/); it points to an [updated location](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/cbook/index.html) for the home page for the book, but that link is also invalid.)

Best practice is to assign the result of a `malloc()` call directly to a pointer object, and let the implicit conversion from `void*` take care of type consistency. The declaration of `malloc()` needs to be made visible via `#include <stdlib.h>`.

(It's barely conceivable that you might want to use `malloc()` in a context where an explicit conversion is needed. The only case I can think of is passing the result of `malloc()` directly to a variadic function that needs an argument of a pointer type other than `void*`. In such an unusual and contrived case, the cast can be avoided by assigning the result to a pointer object and passing that object's value to the function.)

The only good reasons to cast the result of `malloc()` are (a) compatibility with C++ (but the need to write code that compiles both as C and as C++ rarer than you might expect), and (b) compatibility with pre-ANSI C compilers (but the need to cater to such compilers is rare and becoming rarer).

Comment: "_The only case I can think of is passing the result of malloc() directly to a variadic function that needs an argument of a pointer type other than void*_" : even this is partially true, as even if the expected argument type was `void*`, the implicit conversion to `void*` cannot be performed by the compiler on the passing argument, because of the variadic aspect of the function. The compiler cannot perform implicit conversion to a type it doesn't know ! Indeed, the only type of conversion the compiler performs on variadic and prototypeless functions are _default integer promotion_ ...

Comment: ... and `float` -> `double` conversion, nothing else.

Comment: _"In such an unusual and contrived case, the cast can be avoided by assigning the result to a pointer object and passing that object's value to the function.) "_ : even in such a case you would need to cast the passed argument if the source (_T1_) and destination (_T2_) types are different. Failing to do so would lead to _UB_ on architectures where the _T1_ and _T2_ types have different representations.

Comment: The only case I can think of where a variadic function wouldn't need its trailing argument to be cast to the expected type is when the source and destination types are either `char*` and `void*` , as they are compelled to have same representation/alignment per the C standard, making any objects of such types interchangeable. AFAIK this is the only case where neither _implicit_ nor _explicit_ (_cast_) conversion is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: K&R C is ancient.

Secondly: I don't know if that's the full code in that example, but in K&R C, functions are assumed to have an `int` return value if not otherwise declared. If he's not declaring that `malloc`, it means it returns `int` as far as the compiler is concerned, hence the cast. Note that this is *undefined behavior* even in C89 (the earliest standarized version) and *extremely bad practice*; but he may have done it this way for brevity, or perhaps due to laziness --- or maybe for some other historical reason; I don't know all the intricacies of K&R C, and it might be that `void*` to `char*` casts were not implicit back then.

I should add that this is a very serious problem, since `int` and `void*` may have different sizes (and often do --- the most common example being most x86_64 code, where pointers are 64-bit, but ints are 32-bit).

**UPDATE:** @KeithThompson has informed me that the code is from 2nd edition, and `malloc` *is* declared there. That one is (unlike 1st ed) still relevant, if very much outdated at places.

I'm *guessing* that the cast was likely done for compatibility with non-conforming compilers, which mattered at the time, as many [most?] compilers were not fully conforming yet. Nowadays, you'd have to get out of your way to find one that would need the cast (and no, C++ compilers don't count; they're C++ compilers, not C compilers).

Comment: The code is from the second edition (it uses a prototype, which didn't exist when the first edition was published). The cast is unnecessary.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Probably added for compatibility with non-compliant compilers, then. Back then, it mattered; nowadays, pretty much every compiler implemnets C89 (or at least the vast majority of it).

Comment: It's also in the errata (see my answer).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Nice, I didn't know about that. And I think that settles the "cast malloc" vs "don't cast malloc" argument --- the standards committee *themselves* say the cast is/can be harmful. I'll need to read K&R C oneday, just so that I can help other people learning C better (when they quote it).

Comment: The K&R eratta list was not written by the committee.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Ah, disregard that part then. Still, I agree with the sentiment.

Answer (score 1):

People who want (or may want) to cross compile C and C++ often cast `malloc(.)` because C++ won't automatically promote `void*`.

As others point out in the good old days when function prototypes were optional the compiler would assume `malloc()` returned `int` if it hadn't seen the prototype with potentially catastrophic run-time outcomes.

I try to see some point in that argument but I simply can't believe such situations occur with a regularity that warrants the flaming people then get for casting `malloc(.)`.

Look at any Question that casts `malloc(.)` on this site and it doesn't matter what it's about some one will angrily demand they remove their casts as though they make their eyes bleed.

**NB:** It does no good and makes nothing wrong right to cast `malloc(.)` so it is clutter. In fact the only (real) argument I know is that it leads people to look at the cast and not look at the argument - which is what matters!

I saw code on here today:

```
int** x=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

It's very easy to be lulled into a false sense of security.
The `sizeof(int)` is doing (or in this case failing to do) the work to make sure what comes back from `malloc(.)` is right for the purpose. `(int**)` does no work.

I'm not saying cast it. I am appealing for calm. I certainly think if a novice is failing to call `free(.)` we teach them that lesson **before** we get into nuances of casting `malloc(.)`.